# Remove HTML content using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<div id="users">
<p><input type='checkbox' value= "1" checked>one</p>
<p><input type='checkbox' value= "2" checked>two</p>
<p><input type='checkbox' value= "3" checked>three</p>
</div>
```

I need to remove the paragraph within my `<div id="users">` that contains `checkbox value="2"` using jQuery.

I know the values `checkbox value=2` and `<div id="users">` and also know its inside`<p>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this succinctly by using jQuery's [**`has()`**](https://api.jquery.com/has/) method:

```js
$('#users p').has('[value="2"]').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="users">
  <p><input type='checkbox' value="1" checked>one</p>
  <p><input type='checkbox' value="2" checked>two</p>
  <p><input type='checkbox' value="3" checked>three</p>
</div>
```

Comment: nice. a bit different from other answers plus my answer

Answer (score 3):

do as follows:

```
$('#users').find('input[value="2"]').parent().remove();
```

This code will find an input with value 2 inside `#users`, and then get the parent of that input (your paragraph), and remove it from the DOM.

Comment: @KevinBoucher, it works.  The selector argument is optional since it's in square brackets.

Comment: $("#users p input[value='2']").parent().remove(); works also

Comment: @Maybe yes, but as per jQuery docs, traversing (find) is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Here how it's done

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[value=2]").parent().remove();

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="users">
  <p>
    <input type='checkbox' value="1" checked>one</p>
  <p>
    <input type='checkbox' value="2" checked>two</p>
  <p>
    <input type='checkbox' value="3" checked>three</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
$('#users input[value="2"]').parent().remove();
```

Comment: btw that won't work. Even if you correct it as $('#users p input').remove('input[value="2"]'); it will remove input elements, he wants remove p element UPD: Too fast editing :)